# Fill parent not working on My list view

Tags: android, layout

Here is my xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="#E7F7FF" android:gravity="top">
    <!-- Header text here -->
    <TextView />
    <!-- Scrollable layout -->
    <ScrollView >
          <RelativeLayout android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_marginTop="5dip" android:layout_width="fill_parent">       
            <LinearLayout >
                <ImageView />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout >
                <TextView  />
                <TextView />
                <FrameLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <ListView android:id="@+id/contact_number_list_view" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="fill_parent"                   
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp" android:layout_marginBottom="1dp" android:layout_marginRight="5dip" android:clickable="true"
                        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" android:divider="@android:color/transparent" android:dividerHeight="2dip" android:fastScrollEnabled="true" 
                        android:fadeScrollbars="true" android:listSelector="@drawable/rounded_corner_item_selecter" android:layout_gravity="top"></ListView>
                    <TextView />    
                </FrameLayout>      
            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- Show tags details layout -->
            <LinearLayout  >
            <TableLayout > 

            </TableLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>       
    <!-- Now button layouts here -->  
    <LinearLayout >
        <Button />
        <Button/>
        <Button />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And I want to expand list view as what number of data in it. But It is not expand in size. Why?

Comment: You should never, ever, ever put a ListView inside a ScrollView that defeats the purpose of a ListView. If you have diverse items you want to scroll, put them in the ListView and use the typing system of Adapter.

Comment: thank ........... have u ever read the selected answer dude? By the way thank u very much

Comment: Yes, I saw what you marked as the answer. However, my comment still stands. If you want List behavior use ListView, and if your rows are different, you would use the typing system in Adapter. A LinearLayout is not a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained by the programmers that did the listView in this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70) from GoogleIo never put a ListView inside a scroll View. If your list should not scroll use a ViewGroup like a linear Layout and add all the items to this ViewGroup in a loop in your code. If you want a whole row to be clickable you have to use another ViewGroup as the root node for each row and add the OnClickListener to this View.

So just replace your `ListView` with `LinearLayout` as

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/linear_layout_which_is_present_at_place_of_list_view"                                      
android:orientation="vertical"/>
<TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
```

and Let you were using two TextView as custom row of list view. So custom row view will be
 row_view_layout.xml as

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">       
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:clickable="true"        
android:id="@+id/row_view_layout_text1"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<TextView android:id="@+id/row_view_layout_text2"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:clickable="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Sample Code:

```
//Let you were using two TextView as custom row of list view.
LinearLayout list = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_which_is_present_at_place_of_list_view);
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
list.removeAllViews(); //Remove previously created views
for(String row : getAllRow()) {
       View vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_view_layout, null);
       textOne = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.row_view_layout_text1);
       textTwo = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.row_view_layout_text2);

       final String t1 = row.getFirstValue();
       final String t2 = row.getSecondValue();

       textOne.setText(t1);
       textTwo.setText(t2);

       //Set listener for both text views

       textOne.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 Toast.makeText(context, "You clicked on : " + t1  , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
        });

       textTwo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {                
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 Toast.makeText(context, "You clicked on : "  + t2 , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
       });

       //Add view          
       list.addView(vi);
}
```

Hope this will help.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <FrameLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <ListView android:id="@+id/contact_number_list_view" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="fill_parent"                   
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp" android:layout_marginBottom="1dp" android:layout_marginRight="5dip" android:clickable="true"
                        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" android:divider="@android:color/transparent" android:dividerHeight="2dip" android:fastScrollEnabled="true" 
                        android:fadeScrollbars="true" android:listSelector="@drawable/rounded_corner_item_selecter" android:layout_gravity="top">

//HERE PUT THE ITEM VIEWS ELEMENTS OF THE LISTIVIEW

</ListView>
```

I cant see anything else that might be causing your problem...

Comment: Is there any problem to use ListView in <ScrollView >?

Comment: Listview will allow you to scroll when you add more elements. If I got what you said correctly.

Comment: @user594955 Yes there will be problem. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Set width and height of `ScrollView`
Something like this :

```
<ScrollView 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent">

     <!-- Contents -->

</ScrollView>
```